# Jekyll filter by tags with URL parameter

Tags: ruby, tags, jekyll

I'm developing a static Jekyll website (for a personal portfolio). I have 9 posts (projects) and each of those projects contains a set of different (or similar) tags. For example, my front matter for "Project A" is:

```
tags: 
- html5 
- css3
- angularjs
- phonegap
- mobile
```

and "Project B" is:

```
tags: 
- html5 
- javascript
- c#
```

So obviously the similar tag is *html5*.

I retrieve those tags on my page like this:
(and I do this on a markdown file, where I store my posts content, but could do it on *_layout/post.html* if needed.)

```
<ul class="tags">
    {% for tag in page.tags %}
        <li><a>{{ tag }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### Question

How would I go about being able to click on a tag (for example if I click **html5**) and have it should show me all the posts that share the same tag? I would assume the URL would look something like this: **mywebsite.com/portfolio/html5** or something similar. Also the `<a>` tag would be something like this: `<a href="/portfolio/{{tag}}">{{ tag }}</a>`

Is something like this possible with Jekyll? Or even if categories was a better option to use, I could go that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on google with keywors "tags in jekyll" you can found what do you want.

Well, I try to explain using tags in jekyll..

Create `tag_gen.rb` on `_plugins` directory, and put this code

```
module Jekyll
  class TagIndex < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, tag)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dir
      @name = 'index.html'
      self.process(@name)
      self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), 'tag_index.html')
      self.data['tag'] = tag
      tag_title_prefix = site.config['tag_title_prefix'] || 'Posts Tagged &ldquo;'
      tag_title_suffix = site.config['tag_title_suffix'] || '&rdquo;'
      self.data['title'] = "#{tag_title_prefix}#{tag}#{tag_title_suffix}"
    end
  end
  class TagGenerator < Generator
    safe true
    def generate(site)
      if site.layouts.key? 'tag_index'
        dir = site.config['tag_dir'] || 'tag'
        site.tags.keys.each do |tag|
          write_tag_index(site, File.join(dir, tag), tag)
        end
      end
    end
    def write_tag_index(site, dir, tag)
      index = TagIndex.new(site, site.source, dir, tag)
      index.render(site.layouts, site.site_payload)
      index.write(site.dest)
      site.pages << index
    end
  end
end
```

Create `tag_index.html` on your `_layouts` directory and put this (you can customize to your taste) :

```
---
layout: default
---
<h2 class="post_title">{.{page.title}}</h2>
<ul>
  {.% for post in site.posts %}
  {.% for tag in post.tags %}
  {.% if tag == page.tag %}
  <li class="archive_list">
    <time style="color:#666;font-size:11px;" datetime='{.{post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d"}}'>{.{post.date | date: "%m/%d/%y"}}</time> <a class="archive_list_article_link" href='{.{post.url}}'>{.{post.title}}</a>
    <p class="summary">{.{post.summary}}
    <ul class="tag_list">
      {.% for tag in post.tags %}
      <li class="inline archive_list"><a class="tag_list_link" href="/tag/{.{ tag }}">{.{ tag }}</a></li>
      {.% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
  {.% endif %}
  {.% endfor %}
  {.% endfor %}
</ul>
```

source : [tags in jekyll](http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/)

Or You can try this plugin [related_posts-jekyll_plugin](https://github.com/LawrenceWoodman/related_posts-jekyll_plugin)

> This is a jekyll plugin that overrides the built in related_posts
>   function to calculate related posts based on a posts' tags.

Installation :

copy `_plugins/related_posts.rb` [here](https://github.com/LawrenceWoodman/related_posts-jekyll_plugin/blob/master/_plugins/related_posts.rb) to the `_plugins` directory of your project.

Usage :

Put this code to `_includes` directory of your project, and naming file `related_post.html` or whatever.

```
{% for post in site.related_posts %}
  <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

And last, put this code to `_layouts/post.html`

```
{% include related_post.html %}
```

Comment: The first one seemed to work the best, although I couldn't get the second one to do much of anything (except throw errors). Thanks for the info! And I did infact Google multiple combinations of "jekyll filter tags" and "jekyll tags url" and "jekyll tag filter", just not your *exact* phrase.